# Git Command to fetch creation-date-time of all files in git folder at once

Tags: python, git, time, creation

I want to fetch (**at once**) the creation-date-time of all the files present in a particular folder in GIT

Please let me know the git command for the same.

I found a Git command for fetching the creation-date-time of a single file:

```
git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aD -- filename.py | tail -1
```

but this command is not useful if I want to fetch at once all the file's creation-date-time of a particular folder in GIT.

Also how to call this git command from a python script?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash, you could use a 'for' loop:

`for file in *; do ...$file... ;done`

using your command:

`for file in *; do git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aD -- $file | tail -1;done`

Including name for readability:
`for file in *; do echo "$file creation date :"; git log --diff-filter=A --follow --format=%aD -- $file | tail -1;done`